# Tic Tac Toe Game pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

Alright, so basically I am to create a tic tac toe game in pseudocode. Which sucks because I can't see output. Anyways,

/*
*Program by: Cory
*Program: Tic Tac Toe game
*
*/
    Module Main()
    Boolean player = true
    Constant Integer ROWS = 3, COLS = 3
    Declare String values[ROWS][COLS] = "*", "*", "*",
                                    "*", "*", "*",
                                    "*", "*", "*"

```
Call Module getIntro()
Call Module showBoard(values[][], ROWS, COLS)
Call Module playGame(values[][], COLS, ROWS, player)
End Module

Module getIntro()
    Display "Hello, this is a simple tic tac toe game."
    Display "It will rotate turns between players one and two,"
    Display "While 3,3 would be the bottom right."
    Display "Player 1 is X and player 2 is O"
 End Module

Module showBoard(String values[][], Integer rows, Integer cols) 
  Declare Integer row, col
 For row = 0 to rows - 1
    For col = 0 to cols - 1
        Display values[rows][cols]
    End For
 End For
 End Module

 Module playGame(String values[][], Integer cols, Integer rows, Boolean  player) //places moves, checks for already placed moves

     Declare Integer row, col   
player = true
For row = 0 to rows - 1
    For col = 0 to cols -1
        If (player == true)
            Display "First player's turn, please input your move"
            Input values[row][col]
            if (checkMove(values[][], rows, cols) == false)
                Display "Invalid move, please try again"
                Display "First player's turn again, please input your move"
                Input values[row][col]
            End If
            values[row][col] = "X"  
            showBoard(values[row][col], rows, cols)
            checkWin()
            player = false
        Else If (player == false)
            Display "Second player's turn, please input your move"
            Input values[row][col]
            if (checkMove(values[][], rows, cols) == false)
                Display "Invalid move, please try again"
                Display "Second player's turn again, please input your move"
                Input values[row][col]
            End If  
            values[row][col] = "O"
            showBoard(values[row][col], rows, cols)
            checkWin()
            player = true
    End For
    End For
   End Module

Function Boolean checkMove(String values[][], Integer cols, Integer rows)
Declare Integer row, col
For row = 0 to rows - 1
    For col = 0 to cols - 1
        if (values[row][col] != "*")
            Display "Player has already placed a move there"
        End If
    End For
End For
return false
End Function

Module checkWin()
checkRow(values[][], 3)
checkCol(values[][], 3)
checkDiagonal(values[][], 3, 3)
 End Module

Module checkRow(String values[][], Integer rows) //checks horizontal win
Declare Integer row, col
    For row = 0 to rows - 1
        if (values[row][0] == "X")
            Display "Player one has won!"
            //player1Win = true
        Else if (values[row][0] == "O")
            Display "Player two has won!"
            //player1Win = false
        End If
    End For
End Module

Module checkCol(String values[][], Integer cols) //checks vertical win
Declare Integer row, col
    For col = 0 to cols -1
        if (values[0][col] == "X")
            Display "Player one has won!"
            //player1Win = true
        Else if (values[0][col] == "O")
            Display "Player two has won!"
            //player1Win = false
        End If
    End For
 End Module

 Module checkDiagonal(String values[][], Integer cols, Integer rows, Boolean player1Win) //checks Diagonal win
```

So 1) please look over my code and tell me if I'm doing something wrong or if there's a way I can make it look better 
2) I need help checking for diagonal wins. 
3) checking for ties

Answer (score 0):

Answering it accordingly:

1. There are lots of modifications to be done in your code regarding condition checking and other "cases" which might result while playing the game. It will be better if you ask your question a bit more specifically.
2. As far as the diagonal check is concerned, do the same as in checkCol and checkRow, instead check for `values[index][index]`, where `index` value will be same for both row and column.
3. For tie checking you can keep a flag variable which will return `false` when no rows, columns and diagonals match.

Update:

2. For the opposite diagonal, you have to check for `values[index][SIZE-index-1]`.

Comment: So what would I initialize index as? would i just set it to 0? Like For index = 0 to SIZE - 1 and size being 3?

Comment: Yes, index will run from 0 to SIZE - 1.